# Can't do anything with APT

Tags: apt

I'm having issues with signond and gsignond conflicting or something, resulting in me being unable to use apt at all.

```
miclebrick@micles-workshop:~$ sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 kaccounts-integration : Depends: signond but it is not installed
 signon-plugin-password : Depends: signond but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
miclebrick@micles-workshop:~$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  signond
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  signond
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 50 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/153 kB of archives.
After this operation, 596 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 448259 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../signond_8.59+17.10.20170606-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking signond (8.59+17.10.20170606-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/signond_8.59+17.10.20170606-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/dbus-1/services/com.google.code.AccountsSSO.SingleSignOn.service', which is also in package gsignond 1.1.0~r509+pkg4~daily~ubuntu18.10.1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/signond_8.59+17.10.20170606-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: It seems there's a conflict regarding the `signond` package. Do you have PPAs added? Probably one of them is causing this conflict